# Javascript and CSS files combining in Maven build WITHOUT compression, minification etc

Tags: maven

Is there an Maven plugin that just combines js and css resources but doesn't do any minification, obsucation, compressing etc? Just simple resources concatenation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the following changes to your project:

1. In your **pom.xml**, `<dependencies>` tag, place:

   ```xml
   <!-- JAVASCRIPT COMBINATION -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>wro4j-core</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. In your **pom.xml**, `<plugins>` tag, place:

   ```xml
   <plugin>
       <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.3</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <phase>process-resources</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>run</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
           <targetGroups>allDev</targetGroups>
           <destinationFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/</destinationFolder>
           <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/</contextFolder>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. In your **pom.xml** (or the parent **pom.xml**) `<dependencyManagement>` tag, place:

   ```xml
   <!-- JAVASCRIPT COMBINATION -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>wro4j-core</artifactId>
       <version>1.8.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
4. Create a **wro.xml** under `/project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` and place something like the following:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">  
       <group name="allDev">  
           <js minimize="false">/my1stJsFolder/*.js</js>
           <js minimize="false">/my2ndJsFolder/*.js</js>
           <js minimize="false">/someFileDirectlyUnderWEBINF.js</js>
       </group>
   </groups>
   ```
5. In **web.xml** insert:

   ```xml
   <filter>
       <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
       <filter-class>ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/wro/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```

**allDev.js** will be generated under `/project/src/main/webapp`.

I am not sure yet how I could tell wro4j to only generate one in target (now you have two - one in the project source files and one in target).

When compressing with yui plugin I only get one in target. But this should not be that big of a problem for you.

For more:

- https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/GettingStarted
- https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/MavenPlugin
- http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/search?search_type=project&project=wro4j-maven-plugin

**ADDITIONALLY**:

If you have any problems with the resource processing try adding to `<build>` tag:

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

And also to `<plugins>` add

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>swf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpeg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>class</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>jks</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>exe</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>wmv</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>jar</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>zip</nonFilteredFileExtension>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>gz</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think most tools will allow you to turn off the minification.

Here is another couple that look interesting:

http://jawr.java.net/

https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/

Answer (score 0):

Looks about right :

http://hammerfest.sourceforge.net/maven-javascript-plugin/merge-mojo.html

Comment: I am guessing this won't work for a maven 3 project (I can see its a maven 2 project dependent). Also the jar is not available anywhere for download. I installed a newer version that apparently supports maven3 (http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/javascript-maven-plugin/index.html http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/javascript-maven-plugin/2.0.0-alpha-1/), but got "No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml" when building. And also I cannot see a merge goal on this one. Is there any way we could get descent library that could deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

I've used YUI Compressor for years. Used to do it in ANT, but there is also a maven plugin as well. The following link is an example for aggregation:

http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/ex_aggregation.html

Comment: I did not find a way to turn off compression. You can do aggregation only **after** compression.