# What is the simplest way to aggregate/assemble multiple (js) files into one (js) file with a maven plugin WITHOUT compression?

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin, yui-compressor

I would like to aggregate / assemble multiple js files into one without minifying or obfuscating them using a maven plugin.
I am already using a yui plugin to obfuscate some js files into one:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>obfuscate</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                        <linebreakpos>-1</linebreakpos>
                        <aggregations>
                            <aggregation>
                                <removeIncluded>true</removeIncluded>
                                <insertNewLine>false</insertNewLine>
                                <output>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/all.js</output>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.js</include>
                                </includes>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/include/*.js</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </aggregation>
                        </aggregations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Now **I want the same js files aggregated without minification or obfuscation in a file allForDev.js** . The goal is to have one file for development and one for production. Its going to be useful to see the whole scripts when debugging in developer tools. If I don't find a way to do this I'll be forced to place a lot of script tags to load all those scirpts (which is not the end of the world :) but I would like to do it in a cleaner way).

I can see that the assemble plugin has the following formats:

> zip tar.gz tar.bz2 jar dir war and any other format that the
>   ArchiveManager has been configured for

**Is there a way I can use the assemble maven plugin to do this?** As much as I looked there were a bunch of examples to create zips jars and wars, but none to match what I want to do. Or did I miss something?

**Is there another plugin I could use?**

*As a side note, I tried using a second execution of the yui plugin to create a second js file, but I had no luck in creating 2 files. I also tried providing 2 yui plugins, with no luck again. I think that's not possible either.*

Cheers,
Despot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would lie in wro4j library. For a more precise setup see:

[Javascript and CSS files combining in Maven build WITHOUT compression, minification etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213998/javascript-and-css-files-combining-in-maven-build-without-compression-minificat/14103119#14103119)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to hassle with the wro4j plugin as me (from @despot's answer) and want to prototype quickly, you can actualy use the old `maven-antrun-plugin` with similar configuration as the following one:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <property name="root" location=""/>
                    <property name="jsRoot" location="${root}/src/main/webapp/js"/>
                    <property name="jsAggregated" location="${root}/src/main/webapp/all.js"/>
                    <echo message="Aggregating js files from ${jsRoot} into ${jsAggregated}"/>
                    <concat destfile="${jsAggregated}" encoding="UTF-8" >
                        <fileset dir="${jsRoot}" includes="*.*"/>
                        <filelist dir="${jsRoot}/.." files="client.js"/>
                    </concat>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This one concatenates all files in folder `<module>/src/main/webapp/js/*.*` (but not files from sub folders). Then it adds `client.js` to the end to make sure all stuff is available for it (AFAIK `<fileset>` has undefined order).

The resulting concatenated file then resides at `<module>/src/main/webapp/all.js`.

*I know the maven phase, paths and other stuff may not be "correct" - this is just a quick example to show the alternative non-invasive way to do it.*

Comment: FYI if you want to dive into all `jsRoot` subfolders, use `**/*.*` or more precisely `**/*.js` in the `<fileset>`'s `includes` attribute.